# need assistance with race conditions

Tags: multithreading

Below is an example of the code

```
#define MAX PROCESSES 255
int number_of_processes = 0;

/* the implementation of fork() calls this function */

int allocate process() 
{
    int new pid;
    if (number_of_processes == MAX PROCESSES)
        return -1;
    else {
    /* allocate necessary process resources */
        ++number_of_processes;
        return new pid;
    }
}

/* the implementation of exit() calls this function */
void release process()
{
    /* release process resources */
    --number_of_processes;
}
```

I know the race condition is number_of_processes. I am trying to understand race conditions. My question is if i had a mutex lock with acquire() and release() operations, where could i place the lock to avoid race conditions. I just started reading about process synchronization and its pretty interesting. Also could an atomic integer be used such as atomic_t number_of_processes instead of int number_of_processes. I know atomic integer is used to avoid context switching but am not sure but is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the code in that way, for mutex lock:

```
#define MAX PROCESSES 255
int number_of_processes = 0;

/* the implementation of fork() calls this function */

int allocate_process() 
{
    try {
        lock.acquire();
        int new pid;
        if (number_of_processes == MAX PROCESSES)
            return -1;
        else {
            /* allocate necessary process resources */
            ++number_of_processes;
            return new pid;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
}

/* the implementation of exit() calls this function */
void release_process()
{
    try {
        lock.acquire();
        /* release process resources */
        --number_of_processes;
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

I used try/finally syntax from Java, it might be slightly different for C++.

Regadring atomic integer - simple replace of `int` with `atomic_t` won't help because there are two operations with `number_of_processes` in `allocate_process`, thus the whole operation is not atomic.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept answer in case you consider it satisfying.